# Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80004005

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, azure-appservice

I have deployed the [following API](https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode) as is to an Azure App Service from Visual Studio.
I have made sure that I have Remote Debugging and Visual Studio version 2022 selected in General settings in the App Service Configuration.

[image]

When I try and attach process from Visual Studio to my App Service I get thefollowing error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In VS 2022, We have an easy and direct way to attach debugger.
- After publishing your WebApp, In Hosting settings we will find an option to Attach Debugger.

[image]

Once debugger is attached, Remote debugging is enabled in Portal => Configuration Settings automatically.

[image]

- Place a break point in any of the form which you want to debug.
- Visual Studio finds the process, all the symbols will be loaded, and debugger is attached.

[image]

Comment: I swear I tried this and it wasn't working yesterday... Well anyway it is working now. Thanks!

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: As for that, last working day it worked just fine. Today I wanted  to continue my debugging on an issue, and now I get the same damned error and cant connect anymore. Did restart the app, reconfigured remote debugging, to no avail.
There is nothing like an "Unknown error" to make your day.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this issue and the above suggestions do not work for you.  We were experiencing the same issue.

"Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger. Operation not supported. Unknown error"

VS 2022
Azure App Service, (Basic)
Azure App Service: debug Enabled, VS 2022 selected and 64 bit

The solution for us was to..

1. upgrade to "Standard" App Service Plan
2. create a Deployment Slot
3. Build & Deploy to new Slot
4. Attach to Process & Debug

Steps 1 & 2 was the magic solution for our scenario.